# Gtk3 - rolling back a failed drag and drop

Tags: c, drag-and-drop, gtk3

I am trying to implement drag & drop behavior for my gtk-gui.
With the code below I can already drag a button around ... howerver I dont get how I can roll back the dragged button to its original place, if it is dropped somewhere. ( I did not specify a `gtk_drag_dest` so far). Here the relevant snippets of my code:

```
GtkTargetEntry targetEntry;

void on_drag_end(GtkWidget *widget, GdkDragContext *context,GtkWidget *box)
{
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box),widget);
}

void on_drag_begin(GtkWidget *widget, GdkDragContext *context,GtkWidget *box)
{
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(box),widget);
    gtk_drag_set_icon_widget ( context, widget, 1, 1);
}

void myFunc(GtkWidget *mainTable, ...)
{
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (mainTable), box);

    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("X");
    g_signal_connect(button, "drag-begin",G_CALLBACK(on_drag_begin),box);
    g_signal_connect(button, "drag-end",G_CALLBACK(on_drag_end),box);
    gtk_drag_source_set(button,GDK_BUTTON1_MASK,&targetEntry,1,GDK_ACTION_MOVE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), button);
}
```

When I release the mouse button while dragging `gtk_container_add` is called in `on_drag_end` and the following error appears:

> Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkButton to a
>   container of type GtkBox, but the widget is already inside a container
>   of type GtkWindow, please remove the widget from its existing
>   container first.

So how can I remove the button from the drag&drop window ? Can I get the drag&drop window somehow from the context ?

**Edit:**

If I modify `on_drag_end` like that:

```
void on_drag_end(GtkWidget *widget, GdkDragContext *context,GtkWidget *box)
{
  GtkWidget *parent = gtk_widget_get_parent(widget);
  gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parent),widget);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box),widget);
}
```

A different error pops up on `gtk_container_remove`:

> (cron-gui:3319): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_bin_remove: assertion
>   'priv->child == child' failed

Comment: Can you not query the widget's parent? I don't know how it'd be done in C, but in python it'd be `box.get_parent().remove(box)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found `gtk_widget_get_parent(widget)` in C. However it seems like that's not the whole story .. I added the new code + the error-message